# How to retain folder structure when compiling test in NPM/GULP?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

I am using this [boilerplate](https://github.com/Dynamit/front-end-boilerplate) for my workspace. When I compile my workspace into my dist folder, everything from my pages directory is copied except for the folder structure.

This is how the structure of the folder actually looks.

[image]

This is how it's supposed to be.

[image]

BTDT and I2PTGH is supposed to be inside the 2019-midterm folder but for some reason when it's compiled the directory structure of templates/pages is not retained. How can I make it so it so my folder structure is copied from templates/pages?

[My gulpfile.js](https://pastebin.com/0QRaQHhw)

```
What do I have to do to achieve what I want?
```